# Graphs for Big O notation

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I wonder if there's any tool/website where I can plot some run times as graphs. Because, the asymptotic notation is often not what I wanted i.e. Don't want to ignore constants.

For example, suppose I have two notations, like:

1) O = (n * log n).
2) O = (n * log n * log n)/5.

It's obvious that 1st one is asymptotically better. But what I want to see how they perform and at which point the second one starts to become better.

A graphical notation where I can enter different equations and plot them them to see how they vary would be greatly useful for this purpose. In my search I found [this site](http://science.slc.edu/%7Ejmarshall/courses/2002/spring/cs50/BigO/index.html) where they have some plots. I am looking for something similar but I also want to input my equations to plot to analyse the performance for various 'n' values.

Comment: Big O is for the wrong tool for this. When you use it, you explicitly don't care for constants, you only look at the big picture (*really* big picture). Yes, constants sometimes matter, but if you care about actual time taken for some range of inputs (as opposed to asymptomic complexity), you should simply benchmark.

Comment: if you really want, use octave plotting, plot() function supports matrix as well as vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you stop "ignoring constants", you're no longer graphing "Big O" notation, but just performing a standard XY plot.  As such, any graphing program, even [online graphing calculators](http://my.hrw.com/math06_07/nsmedia/tools/Graph_Calculator/graphCalc.html), would let you display this, just replace "n" for "X" and you'll get the proper graph.

Comment: wolframalpha is nice enough for simple stuff like this. you can also let it calculate where 1. > 2. `solve (x * log(x)) > (x * log(x) * log(x))/5 for x`

Answer (score 1):

Would [this](http://www.livephysics.com/ptools/online-3d-function-grapher.php) or [this](http://fooplot.com/) help?

If you use a 3d grapher, you can use the other dimension (say **y**) as a constant replacement. 
This way you would be able to interpret results as:

**when y is greater than 5, n*log(n)*log(n)/y is better than n*log(n) starting from n = (actual value)**

Also, you can ignore the 3rd dimension. Or use it if you have a complexity depending on 2 variables.

Just input the difference between the complexities. In this case, ignoring the 3rd dimension and considering **log(x) = ln(x)**, the equation is:

**z = x*ln(x) - x*ln(x)*ln(x)/5**

An you can interpret that as **x*ln(x)** is more efficient when **z** is negative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how they *perform* then you have to implement the algorithms and execute them on various graph. Modern processors with memory locality and cache misses make it *really* hard to come up with an equation that gives you a reasonable estimation.

I can guarantee you that oyu won't measure what you would expect.